# run script from spyder console using relative path

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I want to run .py file from ipython console in spyder. Script also takes csv file as input. But I got `Exception: File src.py not found`. How do I run the script from spyder console using relative path?

```
run src.py input.csv
```

Comment: In what directory are you running the command ? You can check this with the command `pwd`

Comment: directory of console and file opened in editor are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this format, the path to your file is relative to the command working directory. Therefore, with your command, it looks for `src.py` in the directory where the console is running (that you can check by running `pwd`).

Therefore, you should either :

- input absolute paths
- open the command to the directory where your files (the script and the csv) are

Comment: thanks! how do i make console automatically switch to the directory of the file opened in editor?

Comment: This depends on the configuration of your editor. By default, the terminal opens to the root directory of the opened folder.

Comment: To make console automatically switch to the directory of the file opened in editor, goto Preferences->Run and set Default working directory as Directory of the file being executed.